# How do I 301 redirect from the root folder to a sub folder while keeping the rest of the URL string intact

Tags: php, htaccess, 301-redirect

When I first launched my site, it I had MediaWiki in the root and a wordpress blog in a subfolder, /blog/.

After a while spammers took over the MediaWiki site and I had to remove it. The problem is I lost a lot of good content and inbound links from 3rd party sites.

My goal is to redirect the root folder to /blog/ while keeping the rest of the URL string intact. I have a Wordpress plug-in going that will automatically track the 404 errors. As these come in I'll be able to pull the old content from archive.org and give it a new home on a wordpress page.

Comment: Are you using Apache?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) in Apache.

For example:

```
# When someone visits "/" (root) actually take them to "/blog".
Alias / /blog
```

Comment: Clever. I would have gone straight to `mod_rewrite`, but this seems to be a perfect fit for the problem. But perhaps your example should illustrate how he mainly intends to use it, which would be to ensure `/foo` goes to `/blog/foo` and `/foo/bar` goes to `/blog/foo/bar`.

Comment: Do I drop these lines into the .htaccess file?
<br><br>
alias  /  /blog/
<br><br>
I do I need the last / because there will be URL strings after there?

Will this work too?

redirect 301 / /blog

Comment: Ignore the <br><br>, I was trying to space out my text, not use to this site yet.

Comment: Just adding a line that says `Alias / /blog` in a **single line** will probably fix this issue for you. If it doesn't work, read about how to set it up using the link I posted.

Comment: @lesemajeste How would I do it with mod_rewrite?? I can get the home page to redirect but I can't get any of the old URLs to redirect. The old URLs all look like this: http://wikiprotest.com/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: @Jeffrey: You should use `mod_alias` as that's the better tool for this type of problem. But if you only have access to `mod_rewrite`, you'd use a negative pattern to rewrite any URL that doesn't start with `/blog/` to `/blog/+url`.

Comment: @lesemajeste Could you give me the proper code? I've been trying a million variations and I can't get the URL strings to carry over.

Comment: @lesemajeste I've got a bitcoin for you if you can give me a working solution.